# Prototypal equivalent of class declarations in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object, prototype, prototypal-inheritance

I've gone through `Javascript the good parts` by Douglas Crockford and am trying to understand the class declarations introduced in javascript recently. Take a look at this code:

```
class Rectangle extends Shape {
  constructor(height, width) {
    super(4);
    this.height = height;
    this.width = width;
  }

  get width() {
    console.log('getter')
    return this.width();
  }

  set width(w) {
    console.log('setter')
    this.width = w;
  }

  calcArea() {
    return this.height * this.width;
  }

  static numSides() {
    return 4;
  }

  superCall() {
    return super.func();
  }
}
```

How would this translate to the prototypal pattern which is supposedly the `true nature` of javascript?

Comment: please show some effort

Comment: @Thomas what kind of effort?

Comment: E.g., try using a transpiler to see what ES5 code it generates?